# Converting a std::vector<int> into an array from raw memory

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am working on a python interface for a c++ library using ctypes. I know that this is not recommended, but I can't modify the dll in question, so everything has to happen in the python wrapper.

Let's say we have this function compiled into the dll:

```
vector<int> vectortest() {
    return { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

My python script looks something like this:

```
# [ setup dll ... ]
VectorTest.restype = ct.c_ulonglong * 32 

# set the return type to 64bit unsigned 
# integer array with 32 elements (this is just for debugging atm.)

vec = VectorTest() # call the c++ function, vec should now contain the returned memory

for i in range(0, 32): # print all the values
    print(vec[i])

print('diff1', vec[3] - vec[0]) # this value never changes

print('diff2', vec[15] - vec[4]) # this value never changes
```

Right now I'm just dumping the returned memory in an attempt to find the begin() and end() pointers, as those are technically all that I need in order to find the array values.

Here is an output example:

```
754548928240
2850274634992
0
754548928400
1545446976
0
0
140731499719200
0
165212429600621
0
0
0
0
0
1545365980
2850237907016
2850274763904
2850273274168
0
751619281153
0
2850273493592
0
2847563317248
0
2850273493592
140731499719200
2850273274168
754548929040
0
2850238680016
diff1 160
diff2 -80996
```

The diff values at the bottom are both independent of the vector size, so the first and forth element cannot be the begin and end-pointers. I have also tried to dereference and print the values located at the memory locations, but the values 1, 2, 3 are never found.

What I am asking is:

- How on earth is std::vector stored in memory?
- Is there any better way around this that require no modifications of
  the c++ dll?

Comment: So, to answer your first question, it is stored contiguously.

Comment: The vector doesn't *have to* store begin and end, it could very well store begin and size.

Comment: @VishaalShankar That was not the entire question, though, I was thinking about how the metadata of the vector is stored, not the actual array elements.

Comment: @BoPersson That would work too, but where do I find these values?

Comment: @Jontahan - We don't know, it varies between implementations. The C++ standard generally describes what should happen, not how to implement it.

Comment: @BoPersson In my case the code can be compiler dependent, so how would you suggest I approach looking for this kind of information?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how it works.  You need to make a memory allocation for Python. Think a vector is a valid data type for Python? **You cannot return a random size or type of value !** It is likely to work in numerical operations but does not work on types that contain both numbers and characters. All variables are required to have a predefined type(You cannot send other data while waiting for a data type.). Your output is completely error output (if the output is not a default return type number, then all the returned numbers are errors.).

Comment: Please do not add unrelated language tags. C is neither C++ nor Python.

Comment: I'd say wrap it with yet another layer. `ctypes` is purely binary, and there is no way Python knows the ABI of C++'s vector type. The idea is to write a C/C++ wrapper around your original dll, and specifically target the interface of Python, exposing directly the return value of `data()` and `size()`.

Comment: @Gerhardh This entire problem is related to converting C++ vectors to C style arrays, all without using any C++ API. I believe C is highly related. A tag is supposed to summon the right kind of expert on the topic, and knowledge of C and how it's different from C++ is very relevant in this case.

Comment: @UKMonkey the solution there suggests modification of the C++ source, which is not an alternative in this context.

Comment: @YiFei That's a great idea, I'll try that.

Comment: If you also have the *.h* file that normally comes with the *.dll*, you could write a wrapper, or use *swig*.

Comment: Handling C++ STL types from ctypes is difficult because of mangling, and mangling is implementation specific also an std::vector is not a primitive C type so, ctypes is unable to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

[YiFei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5215536/yifei) suggested to create another C++ dll that wraps around the vector related functions and then bind the python script to that dll instead. I'll go ahead and do that, so I consider this the solution to the problem. Thanks to everyone involved!

EDIT: This solution is implemented and works perfectly.

Comment: Don't rush in posting solutions till not sure they work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the thread, thanks for the reminder.